# R packages with dependencies on 3rd party DLLs

Tags: r, windows, dll, r-package

I'm maintaining a package which links R to a 3rd Party (Netica; norsys.com) DLL.  So my call chain is R -> RNetica.dll (mine) -> Netica.dll (3rd party).

My `config.win` script downloads the DLL from the vendor web site and then try moves it to the `libs/x64` directory (and the 32bit version to `libs/i386'.  [Q:  is this still the right place to put the DLL?]

However, when compiling the package on R-universe (I think they are using the same build environment as CRAN), I get the following errors.

```
cp "/d/a/ralmond/ralmond/RNETIC~1.RCH/00_PKG~1/RNetica/src/Netica/Netica_API_5
10/lib64/Netica.dll" "D:/a/ralmond/ralmond/RNetica.Rcheck/00LOCK-RNetica/00new/R
Netica/libs/x64"
  cp "/d/a/ralmond/ralmond/RNETIC~1.RCH/00_PKG~1/RNetica/src/Netica/Netica_API_5
10/lib64/Netica.lib" "D:/a/ralmond/ralmond/RNetica.Rcheck/00LOCK-RNetica/00new/R
Netica/libs/x64"
  C:\rtools43\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin\nm.exe: 'NeticaDLL': No such f
ile
  gcc -shared -s -static-libgcc -o RNetica.dll tmp.def Cases.o Continuous.o Edge
s.o Experience.o Inference.o Networks.o Node.o Random.o Registration.o Session.o
 -L. -LD:/a/ralmond/ralmond/RNetica.Rcheck/00LOCK-RNetica/00new/RNetica/libs/x64
 -lNetica -LC:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/x64 -LC:/rtools43/x8
6_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib -LC:/R/bin/x64 -lR
  C:\rtools43\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: internal error: aborti
ng at ../../binutils-2.40/ld/ldlang.c:527 in compare_section
  C:\rtools43\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: please report this bug
  collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

As the two `cp` commands are not generating errors, I think the download from the 3rd party website is working properly.  However, in the next line `nm` is apparently not finding it.

I think this may be some recent change to the behavior, as my `config.win` script worked with earlier versions of R (not sure when it stopped working, but definitely worked in 3.x).

The complete package source is available at https://github.com/ralmond/RNetica.

I do most of my work on *nix, so Windows often confuses me.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

This is apparently a bug in the mingw linker used by rtools4.3:

https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/issues/15469

The bug seems to manifest when `ld.exe` tries to link against a `.lib` file which was not produced by a recent version of the mingw tool chain (in my case, it was provided with the developer of the 3rd party library.)

The work around is to copy the `.dll` file to a place on the linking path, but **not** the `.lib`.

The fully implemented solution can be seen on https://github.com/ralmond/RNetica